# Create function to generate new values using list elements from different lists in R

Tags: r, list, function, purrr, data-wrangling

I have a 19000 x 20 dataframe that I need to split based on buckets (there are 5 buckets total) and then generate scores for all patients based on mean and sd of controls for each bucket. So far, I have figured out how to split the data and generate the mean and sd for controls based on buckets using lists, but can't seem to work out the best way to generate the new scores.

**Original dataframe**

```
   row_number age length bucket
1           1  11     31      2
2           2  14     30      3
3           3  12     25      3
4           4  13     26      5
5           5  15     19      4
6           6  12     56      1
7           7  17     45      4
8           8  15     31      1
9           9  14     24      5
10         10  16     36      1
```

**Split data into lists based on buckets for all patients**

```
allpatients <- split(x = df, 
                     f = df$bucket)

# Example data for bucket 1
   row_number age length bucket
1           6  12     56      1
2           8  15     31      1
3          10  16     36      1
```

This generates a list with list elements for buckets 1 to 5, with the dataframes for each bucket as shown in bucket 1 example.

**Compute mean for each bucket from healthy patients**

```
# Function for mean
func_mean <- function(data){
  bucket_mean <- data %>%
    select(age:length)
  bucket_mean <- lapply(bucket_mean, mean)
  bucket_mean <- as.data.frame(bucket_mean)
}

# Apply mean function to list
healthypatients_mean <- map(healthypatients, func_mean)

# Example data for bucket 1 
age length
14  41
```

This generates a list of elements with mean for age and length respectively for each bucket from 1 to 5, as shown in example for bucket 1.

**Get sd for each bucket from healthy patients**

```
# Function
func_sd <- function(data){
  bucket_sd <- data %>%
    select(age:length)
  bucket_sd <- lapply(bucket_sd, sd)
  bucket_sd <- as.data.frame(bucket_sd)
} 

# Apply sd function to list 
healthypatients_sd <- map(healthypatients, func_sd)

# Example (dummy) data for bucket 1
age length
2   4
```

This generates a list of elements with sd for age and length respectively for each bucket from 1 to 5, as shown in example for bucket 1.

**Compute the scores for all patients based on mean and sd of healthy patients**

I would like to compute the new scores for every row of a list element based on the bucket. Essentially, for each value of age and length respectively for a bucket:

`(allpatients - healthypatients_mean)/healthypatients_sd` for each bucket

As an example, the final data for bucket 1 should look like this:

```
   row_number   age   length  bucket
1           6   -1      3.75     1
2           8    0.5   -2.5      1
3          10    1     -1.25     1
```

I figure I will have to create a function and maybe use {purr}, but am not sure how to take the output from `healthypatients_mean` and `healthypatients_sd` to generate new scores for `allpatients` based on each bucket. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to split the dataset here for each `bucket`. We can use `group_by` to treat each bucket separately.

```
library(dplyr)

healthypatients %>%
  group_by(bucket) %>%
  summarise(across(c(age, length), list(mean = mean, sd = sd))) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'bucket') %>%
  mutate(length_score = (length - length_mean)/length_sd, 
         age_score = (age - age_mean)/age_sd)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, computing the mean and sd this way uses the data for all patients rather than from healthy patients only. I would like to compute new scores for all patients but using mean and sd from healthy patients only.

Comment: @smicaela How do you know if a patient is healthy or not? Where does `healthypatients` come from in your code?

Comment: `healthypatients` is a subset of original dataframe where I have already filtered out only patients who are healthy, I did not include in my original dataframe example but essentially there is another column with "patient_group" that states "Healthy" or "Not_Healthy".

Comment: @smicaela Check my updated answer. That might be closer to what you need.